# Preventing duplicate SIMILAR relationships when using algo.similarity.jaccard on continuously updated data

Tags: graph, neo4j, similarity

I am computing the Jaccard similarity index for a category of nodes in a graph using the `algo.similarity.jaccard` algorithm from the Neo4j graph algorithm's library. Once calculating the Jaccard similarity and indicating a cutoff, I am storing the metric in a relationship between the nodes (this is a feature of the algorithm). I am trying to see the change of the graph over time as I get new data to add into the graph (I will be reloading my CSV file with new data and merging in new nodes/relationships).

A problem I foresee is that once I run the Jaccard algorithm again with the updated graph, it will create duplicate relationships. This is the Neo4j documentation example of the code that I am using:

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[:LIKES]->(cuisine)
WITH {item:id(p), categories: collect(id(cuisine))} as userData
WITH collect(userData) as data
CALL algo.similarity.jaccard(data, {topK: 1, similarityCutoff: 0.1, write:true})
YIELD nodes, similarityPairs, write, writeRelationshipType, writeProperty, min, max, mean, stdDev, p25, p50, p75, p90, p95, p99, p999, p100
RETURN nodes, similarityPairs, write, writeRelationshipType, writeProperty, min, max, mean, p95
```

Is there a way to specify I do not want to have duplicate relationships each time I run this code with an updated graph? Manually, I'd use MERGE instead of CREATE but seeing as though this an algorithm from a library, I'm not sure how to go about that. FYI I will not have the ability to add changes to a library plug in and it seems like there is no way to store the relationship under a different label such as SIMILARITY2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least 2 ways to avoid duplicate relationships from multiple calls to `algo.similarity.jaccard`:

1. Delete the existing relationships (by default, they have the `SIMILAR` type) before each call. This is probably the easiest approach.
2. Omit the `write:true` option when making the calls (so that the procedure won't create relationships at all), and write your own Cypher code to optionally create relationships that do not already exist (using `MERGE`).

[UPDATED]

Here is an example of the second approach (using the 
`algo.similarity.jaccard.stream` variant of the procedure, which yields more useful values for our purposes):

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[:LIKES]->(cuisine)
WITH {item:id(p), categories: collect(id(cuisine))} as userData
WITH collect(userData) as data
CALL algo.similarity.jaccard.stream(data, {topK: 1, similarityCutoff: 0.1})
YIELD item1, item2, similarity
WHERE item1 < item2
WITH algo.getNodeById(item1) AS n1, algo.getNodeById(item2) AS n2, similarity
MERGE (n1)-[s:SIMILAR]-(n2)
SET s.score = similarity
RETURN *
```

Since the procedure will return the same node pair twice (with the same `similarity` score), the `WHERE` clause is used to filter out one of the pairs, to speed up processing. The `algo.getNodeById()` utility function is used to get a node by its native ID. And the `MERGE` clause's relationship pattern does not specify a value for `score`, so that it will match an existing relationship even if it has a different value. The `SET` clause for setting the `score` is placed *after* the  `MERGE`, which also helps to ensure the value is up to date.

Comment: I was looking into option 2 but I encountered some difficulties when figuring out the MERGE query. For instance, I wanted to do something like MERGE (p1)-[:SIMILAR {score: similarity}]-(p2), but the nodes are not defined if I included that in the code before the RETURN statement. Any suggestion on how to create the relationship?

Comment: I was able to do option 2 but it created duplicate nodes. The information was correct, it just created more than it should have. It doesn't give me the same results as the 'write' feature.

Comment: I adjusted my code using this outline and it worked. I also understand how your suggestion prevents duplications. Thank you!

Comment: @cybersam , here item1<item2 condition is not needed . it can prevent creating some relations when item1 is in topk for item2 and item2 is not in topk for item1.